# Create a fully connected graph

Tags: r, igraph

How is it possible to create a fully undirected graph with 5 nodes?

Using the igraphe package for exampple

```
library(igraph)
nodes <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `make_full_graph`.  Can use `label` in place of `name` if desired.

```
g <- make_full_graph(6)
vertex_attr(g, "name") <- head(LETTERS)
plot(g)
```

or

```
plot(make_full_graph(6), vertex.name = head(LETTERS)
```

[image: screenshot]